# hostname "project-name.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) - using fog and carriewave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, fog

I'm trying to implement image upload to google cloud storage from my rails 4.2 app using the carrierwave gem. Whenever I go to upload the image I get the error `hostname "project-name.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`.

I cant see what I need to do from here.

carrierwave.rb file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:                         'Google',
    google_storage_access_key_id:     'key',
    google_storage_secret_access_key: 'secret key'
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'project-name.appspot.com'
end
```

uploaders/check_item_value_image_uploader.rb

```
class CheckItemValueImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :file
   storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "check-item-value-images/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

end
```

related gems

```
gem 'gcloud'
gem "fog"
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.8.6'
gem "mime-types"
```

check_category_item_value model

```
mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader
```

check_category_item_value update method

```
if @check_category_item_value.save 
   flash[:success] = "Successfully updated"
   redirect_to category_items_edit_path(@guide, @category, @category_item)
else
   render 'category_items/edit'
end
```

edit form

```
 <%= form_for(@check_category_item_value) do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :value, :value => item_key.value, accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png" %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %><hr>
 <% end %>
```

The forms worked fine before I implemented carrierwave for the image upload (would just save a string of the file name and not upload the image). Now that I've tried to implement carrierwave for image uploads I get the error above.

I used the [carrierwave docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), [this post](http://www.tesseractapps.com/2016/carrierwave-uploads-google-cloud-storage/), and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olPk_uHgRyw) by google cloud platform to get what I have now. What am I missing that is causing this error?

Comment: You need to tell the gem that SSL is active.

Comment: This might also help you https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/667

Comment: @13aal I created another bucket without dots in its name and that worked. Post this as the answer and ill give it to you. thanks

Comment: there ya go man, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is while using carrierwave you have dots (`.`) in your bucket.

Create another bucket without dots and it will work.

Here's some [examples](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), seems your not the only one with this [problem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/667)